# How do you incorperate an AVERAGE and LETTERGRADE in a java program which has 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have written a program with minimal errors but do not know where I should place the Average or Letter grade function:

```
package org.education.tutorial;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradingScale
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of students attending your current session :");
        int numberOfStudents = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Also, please enter the amount of exams taken during the duration of the course : ");
        int examScores = keyboard.nextInt();
        AssignValueToArray(numberOfStudents, examScores);
        keyboard.close();
    }
    public static void AssignValueToArray(int amountOfStudents, int amountOfExams)
    {
        int[][] overallScore = new int[amountOfStudents][amountOfExams];
        Scanner keyboardArray = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberValue = 1;
        for (int index = 0; index < amountOfStudents; index++)
        {
            System.out.println ("\n" + "Please submit Student #" + numberValue + " 's score :" );
            for(int indexOfHomeWork=0; indexOfHomeWork < amountOfExams; indexOfHomeWork++)
            {
                overallScore[index][indexOfHomeWork] = keyboardArray.nextInt();
            }
            numberValue++;
        }
        DisplayvalueInArray(overallScore);
        keyboardArray.close();
    }
    public static void DisplayvalueInArray(int[][] overallScoreArray)
    {
        System.out.println ("The students' scores are posted below : " + "\n");
        int studentCount = 1;
        for (int index = 0; index < overallScoreArray.length; index++)
        {
            System.out.print("Grades for student " + studentCount +": ");
            for (int indexOfHomeWork = 0; indexOfHomeWork < overallScoreArray[index].length;
            indexOfHomeWork++)
            {
                System.out.print(overallScoreArray[index][indexOfHomeWork]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            studentCount++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand what "average" means?  How to calculate it (on paper)?

Comment: What I meant was getting a percent based of however many exams were taken

Comment: As I asked, do you know how to do that with a pencil and paper?  Unless you understand that, us telling you what to code will do no good -- it will simply make us complicit in cheating on your homework.

Comment: yes, sure I do. Just add the exam scores together then divide it by the amount of exams/possible points

Comment: So, do that.  What don't you know how to do?

Comment: would I create another class to carry out that function? That is my question really

Comment: You could create another class, or simply another method in your current class, or you could do it inline in the methods you have.  That's up to you.

Comment: Okay, thank you, that is what I really was getting at

Comment: Try it one way, and if it doesn't work out, try a different way.  That's how you learn how to program.

Comment: Well, I don't know how your teacher has told you to do it, but I would have a class called `Student` that stores all the grades, plus student number, name or whatever, for one student; and has methods to calculate everything that you need to calculate for that student, such as the average mark and the letter grade.  You could then instantiate it once for each student, and store it in an array or some other kind of structure.

Comment: That sounds like what the assignment expectations were suppose to be, how far off am I from that? Is my program completely off

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend learning how to use variable scope and possibly objects before doing something such as this.

You never declare any variables in the class's scope.

Most of your functions don't affect anything outside their own scope, and therefore shouldn't be functions. Instead use comments to encapsulate.

Many of your variables are named poorly, instead of `keyboardArray`, which is not an array at all, do something like `kb`, or `keyboardScanner`

For computing average and lettergrades, think 'what am i averaging' and use that as your parameter, with the average as your return type, so something like `static int average(int[] scores)`

Comment: would variable scope and objects help me clean up my "poor" usage of variables or is that something I need to research to figure out a percentage and lettergrade

Comment: If you're learning java then those are absolutely essential topics to learn, otherwise you're treating it like C, which isn't what java is for.
If you're not in a formal class then I suggest using oracle's http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/